# Symfony 2 - same form on different pages

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've got contact form which is rendered on many pages on my site, i need to handle this form in many diffrent controllers. How to handle this form in all of this controllers? 
I dont want to define special route and controller to handle this form, i need to handle it in all of the pages it is rendered on.

Now I'am calling controller acction witch is rendering my form that way:

In controller:

```
    $profileAskFormResponse = $this->forward('MyBundle:Profile:profileAskForm', array(
                'user' => $user,
            ));          
    if ($profileAskFormResponse->isRedirection())
                return $profileAskFormResponse;

    return $this->render(MyBundle:Single:index.html.twig', array(
                'myStuff' => $myStuff,
                'profileAskForm' => $profileAskFormResponse,
   ));
```

And in twig:

```
{{ profileAskForm.content|raw }}
```

I'am using this code i each controller I need to handle my contact form. Is ther any simpler way to do this?
My first idea was to do this kind of stuff in twig:

```
{% render 'MyBundle:Profile:profileAskForm' with {request: app.request, user: user} %}
```

but I could not redirect from there after form send. The point is, is there a simle and fast way to call (for example

from twig) this kind of components like my contact form, the component that not only render some stuff but have some

application logic in it. I would be great to user that kind of components as brick's witch I can put easly anywhere.

Comment: Show how you are calling the form now.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to create a class like `Contact.php` which has all the fields as class members. You can then add asserts to each field very easily:

```
/**
  * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please fill in your e-mail at least")
  * @Assert\Email(checkMX = true)
  */
protected $email;
```

Than you can create a form type for this class called `ContactType.php` and use `FormBuilder` in it:

```
$builder->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'E-mail'));
```

In all your controllers you can then re-use the form. You can even extend it using an e-mail class that handles all your outgoing e-mails and than inject the valid contact form into it:

```
$contact = new Contact();
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // now you can easily inject the class to the one that handles e-mail traffic for example
        $email = new Email();
        $email->sendContactForm($contact);
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in depth in the [Symfony2 Cookbook: Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html).